# Hazelcast Exceptions

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm currently trying to figure out how to detect the Hazelcast exceptions like `TargetNotMemberException`, and `PartitionMigratingException` in advance.

I mean, before we catch a Hazelcast exception, there might be some pattern that will lead to an exception. If we have detected this pattern, then we might be able to find out some way to prevent the exceptions.

The recent log which catches an exception shows:

> Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=1111111111, partitionId=78, replicaIndex=0, callId=0, invocationTime=222222222222, waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=50, name=RecentlyActiveProfiles}, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=100, callTimeoutMillis=50, firstInvocationTimeMs=3333333333333, firstInvocationTime='2222-02-22 22:22:22.222', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', target=[11.1.111.1]:1111, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=null}, 
>   Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target: [11.1.111.1]:1111, partitionId: 78, operation: com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation, service: hz:impl:mapService

Can we detect the exceptions like just setting an alarm for `tryCount`, assuming when `tryCount >= 100` for a continuous time period, there might be an exception later. Is this way feasible?

Comment: Those exceptions can occur during a cluster topology change. And they should fix themselves after cluster is stabilized. Which version of Hazelcast are you using?

Comment: @sertug I'm currently using hazelcast 3.7. Although hazelcast instance could fix themselves after exceptions occur, we hope we can prevent these exceptions by setting an alarm to monitor the health condition of every instance. If their behaviors satisfy a pattern, then we can consider an exception would happen later. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

`TargetNotMemberException` can happen for invocations targeted to a member that has left the cluster. That member is removed from the cluster due to some problem. It can be that member has crashed or just had a network problem at that time.

`PartitionMigratingException` happens when a partition is in the middle of a migration between members but an operation was targeted to it. Partition migrations happen when a member is added or removed to the cluster, in order to balance the data distribution. So these also can happen in case a member is removed from the cluster due to some problem.

You need to understand the root cause of members being removed/added to the cluster, if that's not triggered by yourself. I'd suggest looking at the logs to detect possible instability problems.

Also for `PartitionMigratingException`, it's best practice to keep partition size at most ~50MB so they can be migrated quicker and migration finishes faster. Partition size can be calculated like:

(total data on cluster) / (partition count)

Having smaller partitions can be achieved by increasing the partition count (default 271).

On the other hand, you can play with the heartbeat properties if they are too small for you (defaults are OK in most cases though). Feel free to look at this section for more about failure detection mechanisms within Hazelcast:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Setting_Up_Clusters/Failure_Detector_Configuration.html